# Error ' missing : after property id' when using Jquery ajax function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

In the following code, I'm trying to send a key-value pair and I always get the error:
" missing: after property id "

```
$(".general").change(function () {
  fields = { $(this).attr('id') : "1" };
  $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "ajax/update_general.php",
   data: { fields: fields },
   dataType: "json",
   });
})
```

I've figured that what causes the problem is:

```
$(this).attr('id')
```

But I have no clue why. I've tried to first assign $(this).attr('id') to a variable, and put the variable in the ajax call, but that didn't help.
How can I fix that?
Thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a syntax error. You can't use the return value of a function call as a property name.

You can, however, use that return value in bracket notation *after* initializing the object:

```
  fields = {};
  fields[$(this).attr('id')] = '1';
```

Comment: +1 @Israel: Beware that dangling comma after `dataType: "JSON"`, too. IE7 and earlier think it's a syntax error, there may be other implementations that do as well as it was a bit vague in the 3rd edition spec (5th edition clears it up; it's valid). Details: http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2010/09/literal-improvement.html

Answer (score 0):

When declaring object with {} syntax, ONLY strings (like {'foo':1}) or bare string is allowed ({foo:1})

You should write something like this:

```
var fields = {};
fields[$(this).attr('id')] = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

`fields = { $(this).attr('id') : "1" };`

to this:

`fields = $(this).attr('id') || "1";`

That's if you intended to have something like a default value.

If you want an object, use this:

`fields[$(this).attr('id')] = "1";`